# how to work with topics through telethon?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

I need to receive messages from a specific topic, and send them to my channel.  there are no problems with sending, but when I try to receive a message from a group, I cannot understand which topic the message is from.

(it is not necessary to use telethon)

```
import asyncio


import telethon
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 
api_hash = ""

client = TelegramClient("session_name", api_id, api_hash)
client.start()


@client.on(events.NewMessage([-1001941512580]))
async def main(event):
    print(event)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v1, the topic is inside the [`MessageReplyHeader`](https://tl.telethon.dev?q=MessageReplyHeader):

```py
msg = event.message
if msg.reply_to and msg.reply_to.forum_topic:
    topic_id = msg.reply_to.reply_to_top_id
```

Comment: The topic id is indeed in the [MessageReplyHeader](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=MessageReplyHeader), but not in `event.reply_to.reply_to_top_id`, but in `event.message.reply_to.reply_to_msg_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Both Lonami's and sne's answer are actually correct.

**Messages in "General"**

- If it's a normal message, it won't have `reply_to` attribute
- If it's a reply, it will have `reply_to`, with `reply_to_msg_id` pointing to the message it's replying to.

**Messages in other topics**

- All messages will have `reply_to` attribute, with `forum_topic` set to `True`
- If it's a normal message, the topic ID will be its `reply_to_msg_id` and the `reply_to_top_id` will be `None`.
- If it's a reply, the topic ID will be its `reply_to_top_id`. `reply_to_msg_id` will point to the message it's replying to, rather than the topic.