how to use telethon(tdlib python impl) send_message to a topic
I am writing a simple Telegram message handler using the Telethon library
I'v already used the code below to forward to the specified topic
await client(
    ForwardMessagesRequest(
        from_peer=event.chat_id,
        id=[event.message.id],
        to_peer=config.target_group,
        silent=True,
        top_msg_id=config.TOPIC_DICT["fruit"],  # set topic
    )
)

However, the send_message method and SendMessageRequest does not seem to have similar parameters

class SendMessageRequest(TLRequest):
    CONSTRUCTOR_ID = 0x983f9745
    SUBCLASS_OF_ID = 0x8af52aac

    def __init__(self, peer: 'TypeInputPeer', message: str, no_webpage: Optional[bool]=None, silent: Optional[bool]=None, background: Optional[bool]=None, clear_draft: Optional[bool]=None, noforwards: Optional[bool]=None, update_stickersets_order: Optional[bool]=None, invert_media: Optional[bool]=None, reply_to: Optional['TypeInputReplyTo']=None, random_id: int=None, reply_markup: Optional['TypeReplyMarkup']=None, entities: Optional[List['TypeMessageEntity']]=None, schedule_date: Optional[datetime]=None, send_as: Optional['TypeInputPeer']=None, quick_reply_shortcut: Optional['TypeInputQuickReplyShortcut']=None, effect: Optional[int]=None):
        """
        :returns Updates: Instance of either UpdatesTooLong, UpdateShortMessage, UpdateShortChatMessage, UpdateShort, UpdatesCombined, Updates, UpdateShortSentMessage.
        """
        self.peer = peer
        self.message = message
        self.no_webpage = no_webpage
        self.silent = silent
        self.background = background
        self.clear_draft = clear_draft
        self.noforwards = noforwards
        self.update_stickersets_order = update_stickersets_order
        self.invert_media = invert_media
        self.reply_to = reply_to
        self.random_id = random_id if random_id is not None else int.from_bytes(os.urandom(8), 'big', signed=True)
        self.reply_markup = reply_markup
        self.entities = entities
        self.schedule_date = schedule_date
        self.send_as = send_as
        self.quick_reply_shortcut = quick_reply_shortcut
        self.effect = effect

Do I have a way to implement it? (bty, I'm not very good at using C++, and I can't understand the cpp demo of tdlib)
I hope there is a param like thread_id for send_message

v1 is feature-frozen (or at least, very cold). You need to use SendMessageRequest. The parameter you are looking for is reply_to. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77598755/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/78366651/.

Thank you for your reply, It works!

I didn't expect the author of the library to personally answer the question, or rather I should actually be asking questions in the issue. Looking forward to using V2 soon╰(°▽°)╯



I've seen that questions shouldn't be sent to issue. thank you.


Feel free to answer your own question and mark it as the solution, so others searching for this know what needs to be done too. FWIW, Telethon is not actually based on tdlib; it talks with Telegram directly.
